# How to disable check of free disk space before copying files?

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

I really hate the feature in Windows 7, that it verifies before copying any files whether the files fit to the destination drive. I have a pretty old MP3 player and I want to just select n songs and drag & drop them to the player, and copy as many files of the selection as possible. Windows 7 refuses to copy any of the files if all of them don't fit to the destination drive.

How can I disable this annoying behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

[TeraCopy](http://codesector.com/teracopy) might be able to do this.

> One of the most common complaints about newer versions of Windows is the slow copying speed, especially when transferring lots of files over the network. If you want to speed up your copying or if you regularly transfer large amounts of data and have to stop the process to perform some other disk-intensive task, this program may be just what you need.
>
> TeraCopy is designed to copy and move files at the maximum possible speed. It skips bad files during the copying process, and then displays them at the end of the transfer so that you can see which ones need attention. TeraCopy can automatically check the copied files for errors by calculating their CRC checksum values. It also provides a lot more information about the files being copied than its Windows counterpart. TeraCopy integrates with Windows Explorer's right-click menu and can be set as the default copy handler.

Comment: Never mind, a test shows that it checks too.

Comment: actually you can disable the `Check free space` option in the preferences

Answer (score 1):

Try Robocopy from the command line. It's fast and only copies the file if the file has changed or added a new files...

Answer (score 0):

Windows Explorer has no registry keys or policies which prevent it from checking free disk space when doing a copy or move command.  You cannot therefore disable this behaviour, it's hard coded.  (Source: Killing and then restarting Explorer with Process Monitor running, and checking all the keys it reads from the registry)

As mentioned above, Robocopy is a potential solution, as this does not check prior to starting to copy.  XCOPY also is an option.

If you would however prefer a nice file manager interface, I am going to suggest you check out Directory Opus, as this also does not do pre-checks prior to starting the process.  You can use this to merge your files and the instant it finds a file which already is there, you can tell it to skip all duplicates.  This product is not free.